# how to remove tokens from contract?

Tags: contract-development, contract-invocation, smart-contract-wallets

i copied and pasted code to make a bep20 crypto coin. some of the coin is sent to the contract on each transaction. i want to remove the coin from the contract and put the coins in my wallet. i believe i have to use the function trasferFrom to do that but when i go to do it, it warns me on metmask that the transaction will fail. if anyone can help me i would highly appreciate it. this is the contract: 0x17A70C8c65b7Adf34B6aB6EB849cba324283Ae57. you will notice on bscscan the contract has 711m coins in it.

Answer (score 0):

Youu need to use the this method instead of transferFrom , if you want to use transferFrom you need to call approve function  first , and approve your address to spend x coins and only after you can call transferFrom , otherwise it will fail :
Try first the function balanceOf Your Adddress and if you have balance you can just use transfer(to,amount):
function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success)

value : 1000000000000000000 ( this is equal to 1 token )

If you want to use token on behalf of the smart contract , use transferFrom ,but first you need to call approve  function to approve from contract to spend token.